# Comprehesive information on serial ports and programming?

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

What are some *comprehesive* sources on serial programming?

Ideally they would cover things like:

- history of devices
- current and future uses
- how serial devices work
- protocols
- and, of course, how to program, preferably in C/C++

Comment: I wrote some interop code in Assembly, calling the serial port to control a stepper motor.  Very rewarding project.  If you follow through this completely, you will most likely enjoy the outcome.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) article covers a lot of it, and has links to other information, including

programming for [Linux and WIN32](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/)

and

[Serial Port Communication in VB.NET Programming](http://www.thaiio.com/prog-cgi/VBnetSerialPort.htm)

In addition to that, Wikibooks has a free book on [Serial Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming:Serial_Data_Communications)

Comment: I was hoping there was something thorough out there but if there is no one seems to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I learnt most of my unix serial comms from [Stevens' Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html).

Comment: It's great source for what it focus on but I was hoping for something of larger scope.